# How in Jest testing to match a string which contains a "/" and gives a syntax error

Tags: reactjs, regex, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my React application, I'm writing a Jest testing to test if on screen I get a specific date, time, and timezone.

The test looks as it is

```
test('Local date time format - Europe no UK', () => {
  const date = '2021-08-26T08:06:14Z';
  const timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';

  render(
    <DateFormatter
      dateTime={date}
      timeZone={timezone}
      variant="localDateTime"
    />,
  );
  expect(screen.getByText(/26 Aug 2021, 8:06 (Europe/Berlin)/)).toBeVisible();
});
```

The test fails with a syntax error

```
 Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /Users/jake/Desktop/Trialbee/admin-frontend/src/components/DateFormatter/DateFormatter.spec.js: Invalid regular expression flag (215:54)

      213 |     />,
      214 |   );
    > 215 |   expect(screen.getByText(/26 Aug 2021, 8:06 (Europe/Berlin)/)).toBeVisible();
          |                                                       ^
      216 | });
      217 |
```

I don't know how to make it work with the '/' as it is thinking is a regEx part but in reality, is a slash that is contained in the timezone string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters (i.e. `/`, `(` and `)`) in your regular expression with a backslash (i.e. `\`).

Change it to:

```
expect(screen.getByText(/26 Aug 2021, 8:06 \(Europe\/Berlin\)\)).toBeVisible();
```

A decent explanation of escaping special characters can be found [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping#escaping). The regex can be seen in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/5TK98x/2).

Comment: Unfortunatley is still failing 

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /20 Aug 2021, 06:00 (Europe\/Berlin)/. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div>
        20 Aug 2021, 06:00 (Europe/Berlin)
      </div>
    </body>

      213 |     />,
      214 |   );
    > 215 |   expect(screen.getByText(/20 Aug 2021, 06:00 (Europe\/Berlin)/)).toBeVisible();
          |                 ^
      216 | });
```

Comment: @Jakub I forgot that you also need to escape the parentheses as these are special characters in regular expressions too. Ive updated the answer. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/5TK98x/2) for the regex in action.